# Format of datetime in std::get_time

Tags: c++

How to modify this code to be able to correctly parse this string "**22/12/2016 01:12:10**" to the **date_time** variable?

```
struct tm date_time = {};
std::wstring dateTimeFormat{ L"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" };
std::istringstream ss("22/12/2016 01:12:10");
ss >> std::get_time(&date_time, dateTimeFormat.c_str());


 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools
\msvc\14.12.25827\include\iomanip(190): error C2338: wrong character type for 
get_time
 1>c:\...\procedure.cpp(70): note: see reference to function template 
instantiation 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator 
>><char,std::char_traits<char>,_Elem>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>
 &,const std::_Timeobj<_Elem,tm    *> &)' being compiled
 1>                   with
 1>                    [
 1>                     _Elem=wchar_t
 1>                     ]
 1>Done building project "projectname" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: `std::wstring` and `std::istringstream` don't go well together.

Comment: `std::string` with `std::stringstream` didn't work also.

Comment: [Works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/455cafe0604283de).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing wide characters with narrow chars.

For wide chars, the code should be:

```
    struct tm           date_time = {};
    std::wstring        dateTimeFormat{L"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"};
    std::wistringstream ss(L"22/12/2016 01:12:10");

    ss >> std::get_time( &date_time, dateTimeFormat.c_str() );
```

For narrow chars, it should be:

```
    struct tm          date_time = {};
    std::string        dateTimeFormat{"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"};
    std::istringstream ss("22/12/2016 01:12:10");

    ss >> std::get_time( &date_time, dateTimeFormat.c_str() );
```

The following headers are required either way:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: Also, I got Year 116, I guess it is because 2016-1900 = 116, i.e. I just always add 1900 to the output year. Any other "stones under the water" of this string parsing?